# Is there a way to have the Slack Enterprise grid image via the API?

Tags: slack, slack-api

Is there a way to have the Slack Enterprise grid Icon image via the API ?

We can get the Icon image of a Workspace (a team) from the `teams.info` API. I'm looking for the same icon, but for the Slack Enterprise (you can set an icon for the Enterprise Grid)

Comment: Unclear to me what exactly you are asking. but did you already check the official documentation? It explains in detail what how to access enterprise features like enterprise ID through the API: https://api.slack.com/enterprise-grid

Comment: Yes I did. Didn't find anything related directly to Slack Entreprise Grid except for 1 page that was high level. 

We can get the Icon image of a Workspace (a team) from the Team.Info API (https://slack.com/api/team.info). I'm looking for the same Icon, but for the Slack Entreprise (you can set an icon for the Entreprise Grid).